# Confusion regarding "I suppose" or "I supposed."

Tags: grammar

I'm having a little confusion while writing this sentence. In informal English we often say "I suppose" to mean "I assume" or "I guess." In the sentence below, should I choose "I supposed" or "I suppose"? Am I right in thinking that it should be "I suppose" here?

> In the end I supposed I just couldn't let go of that letter.

Comment: You'll have to give us more context: it depends on whether the supposition (not the letting go) was a past act or is a present one.

Comment: I'm trying to convey that at a time in the past I supposed...

Comment: Then you use the past tense. "At the time I supposed I could not let go. Now I suppose that I actually could have; but it's too late."

Comment: [*In informal English we often say "I suppose" to mean "I assume" or "I guess."*] In BrE, "I guess" is considered informal, "I suppose" neutral. ( https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/guess )  Could be different in AmE.  (Purely AmE dictionaries don't mark either word as informal - although the American edition of ODO does so in the case of "guess".)

Comment: @rjpond *everything* tends to be less formal on this side of the world.  *I guess* and *I suppose* are more or less equivalent, at least in everyday conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends entirely on *when* you want the listener to place the *supposing*.  If you're telling a story where, at the time, you imagined a particular reason something happened, then the past tense is appropriate.

> I **supposed** she still loved me, in her own way.

= *At the time*, I guessed that she loved me

However if you are thinking back on a past event, and *at this present moment* making some kind of conjecture about why you did something, then use the present tense.

> I **suppose** she still loved me, in her own way.

= *As I tell you this*, I guess that she loved me *at that time*.

Ordinarily you would use the present tense in either case, *unless* it is important to understand your thoughts in the past -- possibly because you think differently now.

> (Back then) I **supposed** that she loved me, in her own way ... but now I understand she never really loved me at all.